# How to remove rel=canonical from tag pages in WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a website built with WordPress and I want to noindex my tag pages but I've noticed that, although I've marked them as noindex, Yoast SEO plugin still adds rel=canonical tag.

Google says rel=canonical and noindex directives must not be together. So, I tried to remove canonical tag adding the following code to my functions.php file:

```
if ( is_tag() ) {
   add_filter( 'wpseo_canonical', '__return_false' );
   remove_action('wp_head', 'rel_canonical');
}
```

But nothing happened. The canonical tag is still there.

Do you know how I can remove it?

Answer (score 0):

By adding only this code to your functions.php you can remove rel="canonical" tag:

```
add_filter( 'wpseo_canonical', '__return_false' );
```

Comment: But in this case I remove rel="canonical" from all pages. I only want to remove it from 'tag pages'.

Comment: To remove only from 'tag pages' add this code in header.php :  <?php
if ( is_tag() ) {
   add_filter( 'wpseo_canonical', '__return_false' );
}
?>

Answer (score 0):

Edit tag.php file in your theme's directory and remove the concerned code or add a file named tag-slug.php to your theme's directory and then build a custom template for your tag archives.